# Ubuntu routing table with 3 NICs

Tags: networking, router

I want to configure Ubuntu 12.04 as a router.
This Ubuntu PC has 3 network cards

```
eth0:192.168.1.203 (LAN1)
eth1:172.16.30.21 (Internet)
eth2:10.216.1.107 (LAN2)
```

and

```
$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Indic Metric   Ref  Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.30.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0        0    0   eth1
10.216.1.0      10.216.1.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0        0    0   eth2
10.216.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1        0    0   eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000     0    0   eth2
172.16.30.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1        0    0   eth1
192.168.0.0     192.168.1.3     255.255.0.0     UG    0        0    0   eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1        0    0   eth0
```

If I configure another Windows PC (PC1) like this :

```
ip:192.168.1.29
mask:255.255.255.0
gw:192.168.1.203
```

From this PC (PC1), I am connected to the Internet and I can ping all IPs in this range  192.168.0.0/16 and this IP 10.216.1.107.but i cannot ping the other IPs in this range 10.216.1.0/24 (i can ping this range from ubuntu pc).

My problem is how to modify my route table to assure a connection between PC1 and all PCs in 10.216.1.0/24 range

[image]

Comment: Depending on how robust this needs to be, you might want to look at the quagga package, or at the vyatta (Debian-based but not Ubuntu) system.

Comment: This covers the same ground as http://askubuntu.com/questions/250370/how-to-route-3-nics-and-3-subnets , but that Q/A is not very enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computers in network 10.216.1.0/24 don't know the route to network 192.168.1.0/24, that's why they can't communicate. You have to set a static route in router2 redirecting 192.168.1.0/24 to 10.216.1.107.

Alternatively, you can masquerade the 192.168.1.0/24 network behind eth2 IP address using iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

The packages leaving eth2 will have their source IP changed to 10.216.1.107.

Comment: this command `iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE` return this error `iptables: Invalid argument. Run 'dmesg' for more information.`

Comment: @YezzySarl sorry, answer updated.

Comment: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE` its the best. thanks